# How to use CDK overlay while leaving an existing component in the foreground?

Tags: angular-material, angular-cdk

The Angular Material CDK library provides various features including overlays. All the examples I can find show how to display a new component on top of the overlay. My goal is a little different. I want to display an *existing* component (one of several on the screen) on top of the overlay.

The behavior I have in mind is that when the user goes into a kind of editing mode on a particular object, the component representing that object would sort of "float" on top of an overlay, until editing is done or cancelled.

Is there any straightforward way to do that? It seems that the `cdkConnectedOverlay` directive might be useful, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

Angular CDK Provides you two ways to achieve that (**Directives and Services**).

Using the `Overlay` service you will need to call the `create` method passing the `positionStrategy` prop:

```
@Component({
    ....
})
class AppComponent {

    @ViewChild('button') buttonRef: ElementREf;

    ...

    ngOnInit() {
        const overlayRef = overlay.create({
            positionStrategy: getOverlayPosition(),
            height: '400px',
            width: '600px',
        });

        const userProfilePortal = new ComponentPortal(UserProfile);
        overlayRef.attach(userProfilePortal);
    }

    getOverlayPosition(): PositionStrategy {
        this.overlayPosition = this.overlay.position()
        .connectedTo(
            this.buttonRef,
            {originX: 'start', originY: 'bottom'},
            {overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'top'}
        )

        return this.overlayPosition;
    }

    ...
}
```

I made an example to show you how to use the **CDK** overlays services and classes.

[Overlay demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdkoverlay?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

If you prefer the directive way Look at this medium article and check the examples applying the directive way:

[Material CDK Overlay with RxJS](https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/material-cdk-overlay-with-rxjs-e6e4a7923229)

Comment: Thank you very much. If I understand your answer correctly, it will create a *new* `UserProfile` component over the overlay. However, I want to show an **existing** component over the overlay, if that's possible, which is what my question was asking.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I think you can change the **component portal** for a **template portal** and reference it out in the different states of your app. [https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/api#TemplatePortal]